# How to Meteor publish & subscribe the user logining data in everywhere?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

May anyone help me? I have question about Meteor that how to keep data of the user logining can be published & subcribed in everywhere?
I created a collection like the Users collections of the Meteor and code a login function another, but after a user login, I can't keep their data subscribe in everywhere.
Sorry, I'm not good at English!
Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks all, I found the answer.
It seems Meteor uses HTML5 localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user is logged in, you can call `Meteor.user()` anywhere in your code to access the user object.

Comment: Additionally if you just want a shortcut to the user id, hit Meteor.userId

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.publish(null, function userData() {
    if (!this.userId) {
        return this.ready();
    }
    return Meteor.users.find(this.userId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @tomsp, but I will try use Session and token

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I found the answer. It seems Meteor uses HTML5 localStorage
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxeHY.png)